Отображение изображения из SQLite
Работаю в Godot. Есть таблица, в которой хранятся изображения. Загружаю их следующим образом
    var img = texture.get_image().save_jpg_to_buffer()
    dict["CoverImg"] = img
    db.insert_row(tableName,dict)

А при попытке загрузить данные назад и создать из них изображение получаю ошибку
Expected Image data size of 683x1022x3 (RGB8 without mipmaps) = 2094078 bytes, got 113150 bytes instead.
Код такой:
var image_string = array_reading[11]["CoverImg"]
var image = Image.new()
image.create_from_data(width, height, false, format, image_string)
var texture = ImageTexture.new()
texture.create_from_image(image)
$BookCover.texture = texture

Высоту, ширину и формат тоже сохраняю в таблицу, там ошибки быть не должно
    var img = texture.get_image()
    width =  img.get_width()
    height = img.get_height()
    format = img.get_format()

Вероятно, причина в Packed Byte Array, но. что с этим сделать, нагуглить не получается

Вы храните jpeg, а загружаете как несжатое изображение. Используйте метод load_jpg_from_buffer.

В какой момент его использовать?

Вместо image.create_from_data(width, height, false, format, image_string) добавила image.load_jpg_from_buffer(image_string), ошибка пропала, даже какая-то текстура подгружается в узел, но ничего не отображается

В дополнении к этому надо было поменять texture.create_from_image(image) на texture.set_image(image)
